# Finding a long vertex-disjoint cycle in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, cycle, approximation, hamiltonian-cycle

I have a directed graph with 562 vertices and 3961 edges (the edges are http://a3nm.net/share/raw_graph_284374.txt if you are curious) and I would like to find a cycle in this graph which does not go twice through the same vertex and is as long as possible.

I am aware that this problem is NP-hard (by reduction from the hamiltonian cycle problem), but I don't really care about finding *the* longest cycle, just a reasonably long cycle. A naive DFS implementation can find cycles of length 100-200, but I'm sure that there are many heuristics and improvements that one could use to find a longer one.

Is there any (open-source) program or library that I could use to find a longer cycle in a graph of this size?

Comment: No great suggestion for an answer from me, but the data set you linked has 562 vertices and 3961 edges. My stab at DFS finds cycles ~200 vertices here (differs each time since I shuffle the order in which edges are considered).

Comment: Oh, apologies, I was testing against the wrong file. I edited the question accordingly. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your problem. Note that when a cycle loses an edge it turns into a path. So, basically, you can do as follows

1) consider each pair of nodes u,v.

2) remove the edge between the two nodes.

3) find the longest path (or approximate longest path) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

4) the combination of the removed edge and the path will provide you a long cycle.

And I think if you try to make your graph a DAG (directed acyclic graph) using a BFS then you can solve the problem of longest path in linear time and exact (with no approximation).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! Do you know an implementation of the longest path or approximate longest path problem?

Comment: I don't know about the approximation case but about the exact case I remember reading some in the Introduction to Algorithms book (Coremen)